# How to track conversion funnel in Google Analytics where a banner ad is shown on many pages.

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website that features a call to action/promotion button on nearly all pages of the site.

I have currently configured a conversion funnel that shows me how many people arrive on the call to action page, and then how many people make it to successfully complete the action page.

What I want to see though is how many unique visitors over the reporting see the banner at the top of the funnel.

**eg. Something like this:**

> Visitors accessing website: 1000
>
> Visitors clicked on call to action page: 100
>
> Visitors successfully submitted call to action form: 45

My initial thoughts was to do this using the frontpage only, but I forgot that this banner/call to action ad is featured on many pages around the website. Many people find the site through SEO and never even pass through the frontpage.

Is it possible to use a wildcard for a domain or something similar in Google Analytics? Or maybe I am approaching this the wrong way.

Last of all - I know I can accomplish this by pulling up 2 reports: site wide unique visitors and comparing that to how many people hit the first stage of the existing conversion funnel. But it's a hassle to have to do this regularly manually.

Answer (score 0):

While using funnel analysis, it is normal to have funnel steps that represent more than 1 urls. Take the basic case of ecommerce sites, where the final goal maybe the same transaction completion page, but the funnel step corresponding to product page can be triggered by many different product pages and not just one.

Based on the page url structure of your website, you can choose any of the below 2 [match types](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en#matchTypes) to add multiple urls to a single step:

1, **Begins with** : If all the different pages displaying the ad have a set of common characters in the beginning, then use this.

2, **Regular Expression Match** : If the different pages that contain your banner ad how totally unrelated url, then find a suitable regex that can capture all those urls